# Error: The key is invalid JQuery syntax because it is missing a closing bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am getting this error in chrome console while trying to request a response from a government private API test server that I'm working against. It says syntax is wrong but I don't see the missing bracket at all. 
Edge console gave extra error text

```
BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
```

Otherwise Edge is the same error as in chrome:

```
    {"Message":"The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState":{"message":[
  "The key is invalid JQuery syntax because it is missing a closing bracket\r\nParameter name: key"]}},
     "status":400,
     "statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

I'm just writing a test request trying to post an xml form to the expected message inbox on the testserver. (the government testserver not mine)

I've tried alot of variations plus looking at the api documentation for possible explanations. 
Here is the code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var postData = "";
    var xmltext = "";
    $.get('TiltakUtenAnsvarsrett.xml', function(tiltakutenansvarsrettXML) {
      xmltext = tiltakutenansvarsrettXML;
      //xmltest = xmltext.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
      console.log("Dette er xmltext variablen" + xmltext);

      //console.log("Dette er xmltext variablen stringified" + JSON.stringify(xmltext));
    }, 'text');
    $("#formtext").click(function() {

      this.postData = {
        "Type": "FormTask",
        "ServiceCode": "4373",
        "ServiceEdition": "1",
        "_embedded": {
          "forms": [{
              "Type": "MainForm",
              "DataFormatId": "5508",
              "DataFormatVersion": "41083",
              "FormData": xmltext
            }

          ],
          "attachments": [{
            "Filename": "String example",
            "Attachmenttype": "String example 2",
            "Data": "Base64 encoded"
          }]
        }
      };
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://xxx.xxxx.xx/api/my/messages",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/hal+json",
          "ApiKey": "xxxxxxx",
        },
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(this.postData),
        success: function(data, status, jqHxr) {
          console.log("====== Returned messages ======");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(jqHxr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Kaster feil status");
          console.log("jqHxr er: " + JSON.stringify(jqHxr) + "\n");
          console.log("Status er: " + textStatus + "\n");
          console.log("Erroren er: " + errorThrown + "\n");
          console.log("postData er: " + JSON.stringify(this.postData) + "\n");
          console.log("Responsetext er: " + jqHxr.responseText);
          console.log();
        }.bind(this)
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Google searches gave only a few cases of this error message not enough to go on.

Comment: Please don't misuse tags.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what to tag this as since it isn't clear that it's actually a jquery issue.

Comment: I am talking about the mvc tag

Comment: You should add `contentType:'application/json',` to the ajax call.

Comment: `"FormData": xmltext` - check if  xmltext is non empty when you create this.postData. I don't have any other idea

Comment: @ Sagar V Yes the API server is using asp.net mvc as i understand it.  Some google searches hinted loosely that it might be asp.net mvc that was creating the error message not JQuery. That said it's not directly relevant since my own code isn't mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service is expecting a JSON, add contentType json

```
type: "POST",
contentType:"application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(this.postData),
success: function(data, status, jqHxr) {
```

Comment: No, the OP should stringify it

Comment: This might be the correct answer. I had overlooked that "Accept" was for displaying GET from the API and "Content-Type" was for sending POST to the API. As I'm now getting the error message "Invalid length for a Base64-Char array or  string". Either this error is cloaking the former or the former has been solved and I'm one step closer.

Comment: Now I have confirmed it was because i had earlier used Accept instead of Content-type. The rest was just errors generated by xsd validating the xml I'm sending in the post data. It worked after I sorted those out. Answer accepted

Answer (score -4):

You close bracket '}' to fast.
This is fixed code:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState":{"message":[
  "The key is invalid JQuery syntax because it is missing a closing bracket\r\nParameter name: key"]},
     "status":400,
     "statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

You can test json on this page:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: So basically... You suggest to remove a closing bracket to the error message OP received ?